# Why $(SolutionDir) is undefined in dotnet CLI?

Tags: .net-core, dotnet-cli

I'm trying to build my project from `dotnet CLI`.

I'm using `dotnet build` and it fails.

How to reproduct:

1. Create a simple console application using Visual Studio template
2. Add a file named `Colors.txt` to the solution directory
3. Add a file named `Names.txt` to the project directory
4. Modify `csproj` file to include a `post-build` event

   ```
   <PropertyGroup>
       <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
       <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
   </PropertyGroup>

   <Target Name="CopySettingsToOutput" AfterTargets="PostBuildEvent">
       <Exec Command="copy $(ProjectDir)\Names.txt $(TargetDir)\Names.txt" />
       <Exec Command="copy $(SolutionDir)\Colors.txt $(TargetDir)\Colors.txt" />
   </Target>
   ```
5. Now build using Visual Studio (it gets built)
6. Now build using `dotnet build` command and it fails. It says:

> error MSB3073: The command "copy *Undefined*\Colors.txt C:\---path---\Colors.txt" exited with code 1.

Why `$(SolutionDir)` is undefined when using `dotnet build`?

Comment: Do you have a solution (solution file) to have a path _to_?

Comment: Yes, this project is part of a solution

Comment: I have the same issue. I'm guessing it's a context thing where dotnet build is only building the project and anything it references. Because it does not reference the solution (it's the other way around), it doesn't resolve a value. Visual Studio maintains a different context.

Answer (score 5):

the walkaround is provide that property in `dotnet` command like:

```
$slnPath = 'directory where is solution'
dotnet build -property:SolutionDir=$slnPath
```

That can be usefull when you use `dotnet` in any build pipelines like Azure DevOps